# Analytically continue a function with Euler product

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I would like to estimate the main term of the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{(c)} L(s) \frac{x^s}{s} ds$$
where $c > 0$, $\displaystyle L(s) = \prod_p \left(1 + \frac{2}{p(p^s-1)}\right)$.

> Question: How to estimate the integral? In other words, is there any way to analytic continue this function?

The function as stated converges for $\Re s > 0$, but I'm not sure how to extend it past $y$-axis. Thanks!

Comment: $$L(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^s}$$ $$f(n)=\frac{(-2)^{\omega(n)}\phi(n)}{n(\mu(n)n*1)}$$$$
f(n) \stackrel{}{=}
\begin{cases}
1      & \text{if $n=1$} \\
\prod_{p\mid n}\frac{2}{p} & \text{if $n>1$}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Let $\rho(d)$ count the number of solutions $x$ in $\frac{Z}{dZ}$,  to $x^2\equiv \text{-1 mod d}$, then we have
$$\sum_{n\leq x}d(n^2+1)=2x\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\rho(n)}{n}+O(\sum_{n\leq x}\rho(n))$$
By multiplicative properties of $\rho(n)$ we have,
$$\rho(n)=\chi(n)*|\mu(n)|$$

Where $\chi(n)$ is the non principal character modulo $4$

Which allows us to estimate,
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\rho(n)}{n}=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\chi(n)*|\mu(n)|}{n}=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{|\mu(n)|}{n}\sum_{k\leq \frac{x}{n}}\frac{\chi(k)}{k}=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{|\mu(n)|}{n}(L(1,\chi)+O(\frac{n}{x}))=L(1,\chi)\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{|\mu(n)|}{n}+O(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{|\mu(n)|}{n}+O(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}(\frac{6}{\pi^2}\ln(x)+O(1))$$
So that, $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\rho(n)}{n}=\frac{3}{2\pi}\ln(x)+O(1)$$
Also note that, $$\sum_{n\leq x}\rho(n)=\sum_{n\leq x}{\chi(n)*|\mu(n)|}=\sum_{n\leq x}|\mu(n)|\sum_{k\leq \frac{x}{n}}\chi(k)\leq\sum_{n\leq x}|\mu(n)|\leq x$$
So we have, $$\sum_{n\leq x}\rho(n)=O(x)$$

Which gives,
$$\sum_{n\leq x}d(n^2+1)=\frac{3}{\pi}x\ln(x)+O(x)$$

Comment: Ah, good one. I still want to know what I should have done if I am to use Perron though. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Sanchez Well, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\rho(n)}{n^s}=\frac{L(s,\chi)\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$$

Comment: ah of course. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for unaccepting your answer, but I saw the gap of what I was thinking. The Dirichlet series I got above is actually wrong, which is why I couldn't solve the problem. I am now more interested in how the problem in my original question can be solved.

Comment: Ah nice. I just came back to this question to write up this answer (essentially), except based around $L(s, \chi_4) \zeta(s)/\zeta(2s)$ and Perron. Nice. +1